# How to build an ethereum based wallet with custom UI?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have been interested in ethereum for quite some time now and have always wanted to learn ethereum development.
I decided to create my custom erc20 tokens i was able to create 2,00,000 tokens.

Now i am planning to take it a little further by building my custom erc20 standard based wallet to send and receive or buy these tokens using ethereum through the wallet.

Can someone please point me in the right direction???...

Comment: Check out https://github.com/cryptolandtech/moonlet-core . It's the core library i built for the moonlet wallet, and can be a good starting point to building what you want, do note it currently handles ethereum transfers, and has support for interacting with contracts ( check the tests ) and you'd have to build the tokens support yourself.

Comment: Thanks @MickySocaci for the information.
Could you guide me through building support for the token .